# Expression must have a class type VC++ error?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I am trying to get the program to say what key the user has pressed using Windows hooks. So far I have been able to get the program to say some kinda message when they press a key but rn im trying to get it say what key they pressed but when I try to access the structure that has that data i get the error: "Expression must have a class type" and I have no idea how to fix it. I tried doing: struct -> vkCode but then I get the error: "expression must have pointer type" So i am at a loss as what to do, here is my code.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM keyState, LPARAM keyInfo) {//The function that is called when a key is pressed
LRESULT reValue = 0;//Initialize the return value

DWORD keyCode = keyInfo.vkCode;

if (keyState == WM_KEYDOWN) {
    MessageBox(hWnd, L"A key was pressed", L"Message", MB_OK);//Put this in message box if the key is down
}

if (nCode < 0) {
    reValue = CallNextHookEx(keyboardHook, nCode, keyState, keyInfo);
}


return reValue;
```

};

here is the line where the error is

```
DWORD keyCode = keyInfo.vkCode;
```

Comment: LPARAM is just a long.

Comment: Then what do I do to fix the problem, that didnt help me any

Comment: As described in the documentation, keyInfo is actually a pointer to a KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT.  So you have to use a cast to tell the compiler to treat it as one, e,g, `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT * keyInfo = lParam;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What key was pressed? Keyboard hooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495337/what-key-was-pressed-keyboard-hooks)

Comment: thanks harry that worked

Comment: @RobertPrévost Not in x64 it's not.